# How much can django.forms help me?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have the following model which forms a Many-To-Many relationship between Persons and "Eprint" publications. Each person's profile page will show the eprints referenced through this table, but only if show=True, and in the numeric order of the 'order' field:

```
class UsersEprint(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    eprint = models.ForeignKey(emodels.Eprint) # this has a .title field
    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now this can all be managed from the admin, but I want a user-friendly form to go in the users profile page on the site.

Ideally I want a table with a row for each of the person's eprints, giving: the eprint title (which can't be edited), a tickbox for 'show', and a numeric field for 'order'. A 'delete' tickbox would be useful too.

The default approach with modelformsets gives a dropdown chooser for the eprint listing all the eprints - which is because the form doesn't know I don't want to edit this. I've tried various approaches with overriding fields and widgets but it all seems a bit kludgy, and I'm going to have end up rendering the form in the template line-by-line anyway, it seems.

The next complication is that instead of having the user type numbers to reorder the table rows, I could use a javascript system - either drag'n'drop rows or move up/move down arrows. When the user submits the form, the new order is obtained.

My question is, at what point do I go out of the scope of django's form handling? Should I just drop import django.forms and manage it all myself? Or are there still useful bits in there for even the most awkward forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your use case is particularly awkward, and I'm sure an `InlineModelFormset` can handle all your requirements nicely. The thing to remember, is that the primary concern of Django forms is the **validation** of input data; the **presentation** is (and should be) up to you.

Sure, Django provides some basic tools for form layout (`as_ul` et al), but you shouldn't get too hung up on them. Customizing the way your forms are rendered shouldn't be viewed as a "hack", but a feature ;-)

1. Since you won't be editing the
   eprint, you can exclude this field
   from the underlying form, which you
   pass to
   `inlinemodelformset_factory`; in
   your template, just display
   `form.instance.eprint.title` instead
   of `form.eprint` (`form.instance`
   points to the underlying model
   instance)
2. When rendering the forms in the
   formset, you can check
   `form.instance.show` -- if it's
   `True`, then render the form
   normally. Otherwise, either add a
   "hidden" class to the form's
   container, or render the fields as
   hidden inputs
   (`form.<FIELD>.as_hidden`).
   Unfortunately, you can't simply omit
   them, as that would cause validation
   errors on the server
3. Passing `can_delete=True` to
   `inlinemodelformset_factory` will
   add a `-DELETE` checkbox to each
   form; you can use jQuery to hide
   this, and instead render a delete
   button. When clicked, the button
   sets the value of the checkbox, and
   Django handles the rest. You can see
   an example of this [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/source/browse/trunk/src/jquery.formset.js#96)
4. The ordering can be handled using
   a toolkit like jQuery UI -- take a look at [this
   snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/) for ideas. Again,
   progressive enhancement is what
   you're after here; all your script would
   do is update the `order` field, and let
   Django handle the actual saving when you submit.
   That way, the functionality is still present, even
   if Javascript is disabled (or
   absent) on the client

Don't be afraid to explore and experiment. Not all of Django is documented, yet (use the source, Luke :) If you're worried about depending on a feature that might be removed sometime in the future, you can always ask on [Django Users](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users)

Comment: Is the form.instance property documented? I see it in the source, but nothing in the docs. There's examples in the docs of creating a ModelForm with instance= (e.g. f = ArticleForm(instance=a)) but that doesn't imply f.instance is the way to get the bound object back. I have been wondering where the connection between model form and model object were... This is clearly it, but I worry that it's undocumented.

Comment: You're right...it isn't documented. I guess it's a little like `Model._meta` -- they're both so useful, I hope eventually the core devs make them part of the official API. 
Unless, of course, something better turns up :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no "good" answer to this question, but personally I'd say this is out of scope;) As you say yourself, you can control the types of fields rendered in various manors, but they, I agree, do make it feel "kludgy".

Also, have you thought about the html behind your javascript system? What kind of form would you need with that... How would a view handle that if it was expecting a form rendered by Django's form handling. You could probably do it, but I think it would get real ugly real fast.

I think you'd be better of designing a template with the form from scratch, and a handling view as well. Unfortunately it will cost you extra work to do validation, but I think you will win more time making the form do exactly what you want it to do.

Let me repeat, this is really advise, I'm sure you could use the standard form handling, but I wouldn't if I had to do the same thing.

Comment: Yup, thanks for useful and "good" answer! I've just discovered jQuery's jqgrid plugin which looks like it does soooo much I just have to play with it. There is a dormant django-jqgrid project on google code, and a bunch of other web resources...